# How do you call on a function that has yield in repl in python?

Tags: python, read-eval-print-loop

I was trying to learn how to use yield inside functions, but every time I added yield to the function I couldn't call it. I followed a tutorial and made this

```
def infinite_sequence():
    num = 0
    while True:
      yield num
      num += 1
```

but when I called

```
infinite_sequence()
```

it didn't work. It did work work when I took out yield. Stopped working when I added return. Started working again when took return. Why does this happen? Do you need to call on functions differently when you add in yield or return? Is it just repl?

Comment: Try this: `s = infinite_sequence()`, `next(s)`, `next(s)`...

Comment: or `for num in infinite_sequence():` `print(num)`

Comment: `yield` turns your function into a generator so you can access values using `next` keyword or (in case of finite sequences) simply converting it into a list.